# Как в java заменить наследование на делегирование

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Всем привет! У меня есть код. Подскажите, как в нем можно заменить наследование на делегирование:

```
    abstract class Dog {
    void bark();
    void eat();
    }

    class Shpitz extends Dog {
    void bark();
    void eat();
    }

    class DauchSpitz extends Dog {
    void bark();
    void eat();
```

}

Comment: ну и да, в данном случае - это будет бред

Comment: А есть какой-нибудь вариант решения этой задачи?

Comment: Наверное, имеется ввиду, что от class Dog нужно делегировать всем остальным собакам?

Comment: `Наверное, имеется ввиду` - вы сами не знаете, чего вы хотите? .....Вы знаете, что такое делегирование?

Comment: Алексей, я в этом не силен. У меня задача из учебника, который просит это сделать. Вот я и обратился к знающим людям. Просветите меня, что здесь лучше можно сделать. И зачем нужно делегирование.

Comment: про делегирование мельком http://pr0java.blogspot.com/2015/07/blog-post_83.html  + небольшое видео https://youtu.be/qfKX4xQ4Yos..... поэтому что именно хочет учебник в данном случае - без понятия (может быть реализацию через интерфейсы..вполне возможно). Если он под делегированием понимает не то, что принято понимать, то лучше его выкинуть

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что и не делегирование вам нужно, а композиция. Её обычно используют для замены наследования.